# git push -u origin master, username and password

Tags: git, github, repository

I am currently going through Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, and I am stuck in the GitHub section. The following happens whenever I try to push my repository up to GitHub:

```
Hannas-MacBook-Air:first_app Hannananana$ git remote add origin https://github.com/hannaselvaag/first_app.git
Hannas-MacBook-Air:first_app Hannananana$ git push -u origin master
Username: 
Password: 

^[error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing  

https://github.com/hannaselvaag/first_app.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have created a username and password at github.com, but the terminal wont let me type anything in it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You must use your GitHub account username: `hannaselvaag`.
And your GitHub account password.

Not create a new username and password (like an ssh passphrase) just for that repo.

Change your remote in order to add your GitHub username account in the url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://hannaselvaag@github.com/hannaselvaag/first_app.git
```

Then try again the `git push -u origin master`, entering only your GitHub password.

([check also your git version](https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors))

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the answer. The problem is really that the terminal wont let me type in anything. I did what you said, and the problem is the same - the terminal doesn't let me type anything

Comment: @HannaM.Selvaag do you have some kind of caching mechanism in place, as described in http://lifehacker.com/5983680/how-the-heck-do-i-use-github (with the `git-credential-osxkeychain`)?

Answer (score -1):

For Bitbucket:

```
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/hannaselvaag/first_app
```

For Github:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/hannaselvaag/first_app
```

You just had to remove the .git at the end of the url

Comment: Hannah isn't using or asking about Bitbucket, she's asking specifically about GitHub. It'd be helpful if you provided context to this answer so it's relevant, or directly answered the question as posed.